# Python - read 1000 lines from a file at a time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609237/python-read-1000-at-a-time-until-end-of-file%20%22%22), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657299/how-do-i-read-two-lines-from-a-file-at-a-time-using-python%22%22) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832856/how-to-read-file-n-lines-at-a-time-in-python%20%22%22).

The 3rd link seemed to have the answer yet it didn't do the job.

I can't have a solution where the whole file is brought to main memory, as the files I'll be working with will be very large. So I decided to use `islice` as shown in the 3rd link. First 2 links were irrelevant as they used it for only 2 lines or read 1000 characters. Whereas I need **1000 lines.** `for now N is 1000`

My file contains **1 million** lines:

***Sample:***

```
1 1 1
1 2 1
1 3 1
1 4 1
1 5 1
1 6 1
1 7 1
1 8 1
1 9 1
1 10 1
```

So if I read 1000 lines at a time, I should go through the `while` `1000` times, yet when I print `p` to check how many times I've been in through, it doesn't stop at a `1000`. It reached `19038838` after running my program for `1400` seconds!!

**CODE:**

```
def _parse(pathToFile, N, alg):
    p = 1
    with open(pathToFile) as f:
        while True:
            myList = []
            next_N_lines = islice(f, N)
            if not next_N_lines:
                break
            for line in next_N_lines:
                s = line.split()
                x, y, w = [int(v) for v in s]
                obj = CoresetPoint(x, y)
                Wobj = CoresetWeightedPoint(obj, w)
                myList.append(Wobj)
            a = CoresetPoints(myList)
            client.compressPoints(a) // This line is not the problem
            print(p)
            p = p+1
    c = client.getTotalCoreset()
    return c
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: the `f` is probably not consumed so you end up reading the same and same 1000 lines every time. This will never terminate. You have to use the alternative formulation for `islice` (`itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop[, step])` this one and not `itertools.islice(iterable, stop)` this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Ev.kounis said your while loop doesn't seem to work properly.

I would recommend to go for the yield function for chunk of data at a time like this:

```
def get_line():
    with open('your file') as file:
        for i in file:
            yield i

lines_required = 1000
gen = get_line()
chunk = [next(gen) for i in range(lines_required)]
```

Comment: But won't it try to open the same file `1M` times for each line ? it will slow down the program, is it not ?

Comment: No, it will only repeat the steps in the for loop. Yield can be interpreted as "return this input and come back exactly here when asked to". Have a look at doc for Generators: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators

Comment: @MKesper
And how do if the file is over so I can stop iterating and reading ?
`if not chunk: break` didn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Managed to fix this by wrapping it by `try` and if an exception is thrown then I break. Thanks!